# Awk script: loop through rows and get sum

Tags: awk

I am putting together a (g)awk file script that loops through the numeric data provided from in an input file, and has to sum the values in each row. I am creating an array and adding the row sums to each array position. Below is my code. The logic seems ok, but the output is off:

```
for(i = 1; i <= NF; ++i){
   for(j = 1; j <= NR; ++j){
       row[i] += $j
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot loop through the lines. The loop through lines is done implicitly done by `awk` while reading the file.

So you just need to update the values in an array for the current line:

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[i]+=$i}' file
```

Then, you can print the summary within the `END` block.

See an example:

```
$ cat a
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
$ awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[i]+=$i} END {for (i in a) print i " -> " a[i]}' a
1 -> 7
2 -> 9
3 -> 11
4 -> 13
5 -> 15
```

Comment: Thank you for reminding me. A follow up on you answer: your example indicates the way to obtain column totals. I still can't figure out how to sum ROWS correctly. I find I don't get the expected results when I use the record number value: {for(i = 1; i <=NR;++i) rows[i] += $i}, as I would have expected.

Comment: @user2781042 Not sure what you mean with "sum rows": sum all the elements in a row? If this is the case, something like `awk '{sum=0; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) sum+=$i; print sum}' file` makes it.